# Sum of a array in Java

Tags: java, arrays, sum

I have to make the sum of the below array. It should equal to 73 but I am getting 365 for some reason.

```
class ArrayTask2 {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      int [] intList = {5,20,32,7,9};
      int sum = 0;

      for (int i = intList.length-1; i >=0; i--) {
      for (int counter=0;counter<intList.length;counter++)
            sum = sum + intList[counter];
         System.out.println ("intList [" + i + "]: " + intList [i]);
      }
      System.out.println ("Sum = " + sum);
   }    
}
```

Comment: you only need one loop

Comment: You don't need to put them in 2 for loop.

Comment: You haven't try to debug it?

Comment: Baffled at the downvotes on this - it might be simple for an expert, and it's obviously homework or labwork of some kind, but honestly the question is showing what OP has tried so far, what the requirements are, etc. This is a good question!

Answer (score 2):

Because you are running nested for loops. You are taking the sum in the inner for loop. And in the outer loop, you're repeating this process 5 times, that gives you 365. Remove the outer for loop.

Comment: This is absolutely correct. A quick check of `73 * 5 = 365` is further evidence.

Answer (score 1):

With Java 8

```
int total = Arrays.stream(intList).sum();
```

Or pretty much the same

```
int total = IntStream.of(intList).sum();
```

So the full code would be

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;

class ArrayTask2 {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      int [] intList = {5, 20, 32, 7, 9};
      int sum = Arrays.stream(intList).sum();
      System.out.println ("Sum = " + sum);
   }    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not have them in 2 loops and always try to keep the code in the same pattern.

```
class ArrayTask2 {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      int [] intList = {5,20,32,7,9};
      int sum = 0;

      //for (int i = intList.length-1; i >=0; i--) {
      for (int counter=0;counter<intList.length;counter++)
         sum = sum + intList[counter];

         //System.out.println ("intList [" + i + "]: " + intList [i]);
      }
      System.out.println ("Sum = " + sum);
   //}    
}
```